# Get rid of .install4j directory while installation throws an exception

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j to install my software. I've few components, sometimes when there is missing a .exe that is searched via my custom code and it is not found install4j throws an exception and the installation quits, it's correct behavior. Then a hidden directory ".install4j" is created on the drive I am installing the software. Then when I'm trying to run the installation second time the installation is processing (exe file is placed there where it should be) but I am prompt to replace all files in the directory .install4j, is there a way to do not create this directory? Is it required and used somewhere? If not maybe it would be good idea to delete the file before a component that previously failed is selected. Any ideas how could I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

The `.install4j` directory in the installation directory contains the runtime that is required by installer applications such as the uninstaller as well as the generated launchers. If it is missing, those launchers will not not work.

Comment: @Ingo_Kegel If I am not using the uninstall function for install4j do I need it still? Or how can I avoid the message that I need to overwrite those files when running installation of component second time. Is there a function for that or something?

Comment: On the "Install files" action, deselect the "Install runtime" property, then the .install4j directory will not be installed.